# VB Windows Forms in .NET Core

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-core

I have to convert my VB Windows Forms to .NET Core. To work on multiple platforms. But I am unable to get and I have read .NET Core doesn't support VB Forms. Kindly suggest any other ways. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Forms or Web Forms? The fact that you tagged this question ASP.NET suggests Web Forms but, if that's the case, why do you need to support multiple platforms when it's a web app that will be installed on one web server? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: Vb Windows Forms @jmcilhinney

Comment: It _is_ supported in .NET Core 3.0 and above. See: [How to migrate a Windows Forms desktop app to .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-5.0). Do note, however, that WinForms is only supported on Windows, still.

Comment: As suggested, you got it exactly backwards. .NET 5.0, which is the latest version of .NET Core, does support VB Windows Forms but Windows Forms is not supported on other platforms. Previous versions of .NET Core did support VB WinForms but the VS support wasn't worth the effort. Even now, there are a few things still missing that I expect will be addressed in .NET 6.0 and VS 2022.

Comment: No one should have to read the comments in order to understand the question. If someone asks for information that should have been provided in the first place, edit the question and add it where it should be, not in a comment.